# Rails using a join model attribute in a condition for a find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using a :has_many, :through association to link two models, User and Place

It looks like this -

In User:

```
  has_many :user_places
  has_many :places, :through=>:user_places
```

In Place:

```
  has_many :user_places
  has_many :users, :through=>:user_places
```

In User_Place

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :place
  belongs_to :place_status
```

On that last one note the place_status.

I want to write a find that returns all places associated to a user with a particular place_status_id.

Place_Status_id is on the join model, user_place.

So basically I want

```
User.places.where(:place_status_id=>1)
```

(in rails 3)

but i get an error with that because place_status_id isnt on the place model.

Any ideas? Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do your find this way

```
@user.places.joins(:user_places).where(:user_places => {:place_status_id => 1})
```

I've never used Rails 3, so I'm sorry if there's any errors.